# Pagination in MVC structure

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

Can anyone help me with how I can call a pagination function in a mvc structure?

I links look likes this after the `.htaccess` have done its magic:

```
controller/action/id
```

Before:

```
index.php?controller=&action=&id=
```

What i would really like to do is setting the url like

```
/controller/px
```

Where `x` is any int value

my `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I'm hoping for some help or some pointer of any kind would be nice.

Comment: How do you want to rewrite `/controller/px` internally?

Comment: MVC has nothing to do with the way you build your URIs

Comment: its like i have a frontpage with a bunch of news on it... and i want to be able to add a pagination on it like /home <-- this is my frontpage ... but if i go to /home/view for example it graps my view action within the home controller. my question is really isn't where a way to make the pagination work without saying /home/view/1/p2 ??

Comment: Without pretty URL in place what is your full URL with pagination parameters?

Comment: it is : index.php?controller=home&action=&id=&p=1 or 2 or whatever number :) witch works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this rule **before your existing rule**:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=&id=&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for htaceess file:

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /your_folder_name/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
        # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>

Replace your_folder_name on the third line with your folder name. 

if its code ignitor, you need to make some changes in application/config/config.php 
change the following lines as below

$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

also in autoload in application/config/autoload.php, change to the following line

$autoload['helper'] = array('url');

In Controller

$this->load->library('Pagination');
$config['base_url']=base_url().'controller/function';
$config['total_rows']=$data_count;
$config['per_page']=1;
$config['num_links']=2;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);

While fetching data from database use uri segment  and $config['per_page'] as limits

In View

to get the pagination links 

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```